# How to show error message when the user enters only 0 or 0.0 using regular expression in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, regex

I have a specific requirement for the input field.

- It shouldn't allow value 0 but It should allow values like  0.123, 0.1, 1.0
- It shouldn't allow any string characters.

  Is it possible to achieve this using regular expression ? or I need to write a custom JavaScript function to validate the conditions?

This is what I have tried

```
ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$/
```

Fiddler Link [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KGd8K/2779/)

Comment: Try `ng-pattern="/^(?!0+(?:\.0+)?$)[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$/"`.

Comment: Thanks. It's working. @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may restrict the input by adding a negative lookahead into the regex:

```
ng-pattern="/^(?!0+(?:\.0+)?$)[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$/"
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `(?!0+(?:\.0+)?$)` negative lookahead fails the match (and will cause the error message to appear) once the user types zero(s) optionally followed with `.` + zero(s) only.

**More details**:

- `^` - start  of string
- `(?!0+(?:\.0+)?$)` - there must be no one or more zeros optionally followed with `.` + one or more zeros
- `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits
- `([.][0-9]+)?` - an optional sequence of `.` + 1+ digits
- `$` - end of string.

[Link to updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z426ota4/1/)

Comment: great answer, could you please explain the difference of non-capturing group `(?:\.0+)?` inside negative lookahead and normal group `([.][0-9]+)?`

Comment: That is just a force of habit: a non-capturing group (`(?:...)`) does not store the captured text in a memory buffer while a capturing group (`(...)`) will. So, it is a nano-optimization here, you may use a capturing group if you think it is more readable.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. @WiktorStribiżew